# How to convert image format between PIL opencv web and mongoDB?

Tags: python, image, mongodb, opencv, python-imaging-library

I want to store image from web to MongoDB, but first I will check the image by opencv to make sure it is an Blood Test Report image, just like followiing snippet:

```
if 'imagefile' not in request.files:
        abort(400)
    imgfile = request.files['imagefile']
    if imgfile.filename == '':
        abort(400)
    if imgfile:
        #pil = StringIO(imgfile)
        #pil = Image.open(pil)
        img = cv2.imdecode(numpy.fromstring(imgfile.read(), numpy.uint8), cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)
        filtered = ImageFilter(image=img).filter()
        if filtered is None:
            return jsonify({"error": "please make sure your picture is perfect"})
        # save to mongo
        content = StringIO()
        filtered.save(content, format="JPEG")
        fid, filename= save_file(content,imgfile.name)
```

The ImageFilter accepts a opencv format image, and do something such as filtering, and then return a PIL image, and it succeed! then I save the PIL image to MongoDB, code like this:

```
def save_file(content, name):

    # content = StringIO(f.read())
    try:
        mime = Image.open(content).format.lower()
        if mime not in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']:
            raise IOError()
    except IOError:
        abort(400)
    c = dict(content=bson.binary.Binary(content.getvalue()),
             filename=secure_filename(name), mime=mime)
    db.files.save(c)
    return c['_id'], c['filename']
```

And it succeed! Then i have another function to find a image by id from MongoDB, then I will use it to do OCR.

```
def get_report(fid):
    try:
        file = db.files.find_one(bson.objectid.ObjectId(fid))
        if file is None:
            raise bson.errors.InvalidId()
        print(type(file['content']))

        img = cv2.imdecode(numpy.fromstring(dumps(file['content']), numpy.uint8), cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)
        if img is None:
            return jsonify({"error": "please make sure your picture is perfect"})
        report_data = ImageFilter(image=img).ocr(22)
        print report_data
        if report_data is None:
            return jsonify({"error": "can't ocr'"})
        return jsonify(report_data)
    except bson.errors.InvalidId:
        flask.abort(404)
```

Again, I will use it in opencv format, so I will convert the bson.binary.Binary to opencv image, but it failed! because img always none by

```
img = cv2.imdecode(numpy.fromstring(dumps(file['content']), numpy.uint8), cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)
```

So, my last question is what is the real image format in python, How i convert it in web mongodb opencv pil and memory!,Following is one method i tried, but it failed! I want to convert the Binary to PIL image use Image.frombytes first, then i convert the PIL to opencv. But error:ValueError: not enough image data

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient
import bson
from PIL import Image
from imageFilter import ImageFilter
import cv2
import numpy
from bson.json_util import dumps

db = MongoClient('localhost', 27017).test
 file =db.files.find_one(bson.objectid.ObjectId("58454666a235ec451d3bf2e6"))
if file is None:
    raise bson.errors.InvalidId()

print(type(file['content']))

# this is success, I use Flask Response
#return Response(file['content'], mimetype='image/' + file['mime'])

# file['content']是整个图片文件的二进制对象，也就是说是一个文件，不应该直接作为二进制数据传递给Image
Image.frombytes(mode='RGB',size=(1000,760),data=file['content'])

img = cv2.imdecode(numpy.fromstring(dumps(file['content']), numpy.uint8), cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)
if img is None:
    print "img is None"
# ImageFilter accept opencv img to process it by opencv
report_data = ImageFilter(image=img).ocr(22)
print report_data
```

Comment: Why don't you save the images to disk and store the path in the MongoDB?